# Сумма чисел в массиве, без одного меньшего и большего значения

Tags: javascript

Делаю так:

```js
function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}

function getMinOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.min.apply(null, numArray);
}

function squareSum(numbers){
  return numbers.reduce(function(sum, n){
    var a = (getMaxOfArray(numbers) - getMinOfArray(numbers));
    var b = n + sum;
    return a - b;
  }, 0)
}

console.log(squareSum([1,2,2,33]));
```

**UPD**
Правильное решение  :

```js
    function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
      return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
    }

    function getMinOfArray(numArray) {
      return Math.min.apply(null, numArray);
    }

    function sumArray(numbers){
      var maxPlusMin = getMaxOfArray(numbers) + getMinOfArray(numbers);
      return numbers.reduce(function(sum, n){  
        return n + sum;
      }, -maxPlusMin );
    }

    console.log(sumArray([1,5,5,101]));
```

Comment: Это же надо так извратить логику вычисления суммы, и потом спрашивать что не так. `numbers.reduce(function(sum, n){ return n + sum;}, -getMaxOfArray(numbers) - getMinOfArray(numbers));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4 итерации:

```
     sum   n   a   b    return
1)    0    1   32  1    31
2)    31   2   32  33   -1
3)    -1   2   32  1    31
4)    31   33  32  64   -32
```

`reduce` вызывается на каждом элементе. Вы для каждого элемента используете max и min, хотя должны поидеи всего 1 раз вычесть.

Что-то такое уж должно быть:

```
function squareSum(numbers){
  if(numbers.length == 0)
     return 0;

  var maxPlusMin = getMaxOfArray(numbers) + getMinOfArray(numbers);
  return numbers.reduce(function(sum, n){  
    return n + sum;
  }, -maxPlusMin );
}
```

Comment: подскажи пожалуйста как проверять на пустой массив в твоём коде, если у меня массив пустой reduce получается не срабатывает а выдаёт ошибку

Comment: @stas0k `if(numbers.length == 0) return 0;`

Comment: будьте добрый помогите добавить проверку на undefined. код получился такой:


function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
      return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
    }

    function getMinOfArray(numArray) {
      return Math.min.apply(null, numArray);
    }

function sumArray(numbers){
  var maxPlusMin = getMaxOfArray(numbers) + getMinOfArray(numbers);
  if (numbers) {
  return numbers.reduce(function(sum, n){  
    return n + sum;
  }, -maxPlusMin );
  } else {
   numbers = [];
  }
}


но тесты не могу пройти, пишет : Test Results:
✘ Expected: 0, instead got: undefined

Comment: @stas0k что за тест? что на входе?

Comment: такой информации у меня нет. просто окно и надпись: Test Results:
✘ Expected: 0, instead got: undefined

Comment: @stas0k ссылку на тест дайте хоть.

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-without-highest-and-lowest-number - возможно нужно зарегистрироваться